# return a pointer of vector with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I am testing with the shared_ptr of vector. The purpose is simple, I want to return a pointer of vector and access the value in it. But it gives exception. "Unhandled exception at.. std:out_of_range at memory location ..". I am using Visual Studio 2012.

```
vector<int>* func()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<vector<int> > vec(new vector<int>());

    vec->push_back(123);
    return vec.get();
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int>* result = func();

    cout << result->at(0); // ERROR here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning the shared pointer, you're returning the vector it contains. The shared wrapper is lost at that point.

Comment: @not-TonyTheLion Terrible, terrible comment. Please don't ever write comments again.

Comment: To be fair most people struggle with even the concept of pointers in C - let alone the magic of shared pointers. Shared pointers are wonderful magical things - but not as simple as Java references, for example, so you can understand how people might get it (very) wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use shared pointers, then return a shared pointer, not a raw one. Otherwise, when the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, it will destroy the vector. Accessing that vector will lead to undefined behaviour.

```
boost::shared_ptr<vector<int> > func()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<vector<int> > vec(new vector<int>());
    vec->push_back(123);
    return vec;
}
```

However, note that it's much better to return the vector by value:

```
vector<int> func()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(123);
    return vec;
}
```

This way, there are no copies being made, either through move constructors or [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: "either through move constructors or RVO" or both :)

Comment: You are right. But is there a way to return as vector<int>* instead of shared_ptr<vector<int> >?

Comment: @zwx yes, but you shouldn't use `shared_ptr` then. Just allocate it using operator `new` and return it. This is a bad idea though. The best way is to return by value.

Comment: @StoryTeller well, they're not going to happen both at the same time, right? :D

Comment: @mfontanini, depends on how you define at the same time :D
For instance, the temporary object may be eliminated by weaker RVO, and the result then moved into the object initialized by the function call.

Comment: Sure you can can. There can be at most two copies made in c++03 without RVO. `vec->temp->v`.  Compilers can perform weak RVO and leave only one copy `vec->v`. So back to c++11, the case of moving `vec` into `v` is also in part due to RVO.

Comment: OK. The real question is, I am implementing an API which return value has to be a pointer to an array, and I want to avoid to use delete. So I am wondering does smart point can help me out. Now I think I have to implement destructor myself.

Comment: @zwx if it **has** to be a pointer then you'll have to use delete. If you can return an object, then either return a smart pointer, or the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

The type you return from `func()` needs to be `boost::shared_ptr<vector<int>>` - not `vector<int>*`.

The whole point of shared pointers is you can pass them around as much as you like and when they all stop being referenced the memory they pointed to is reclaimed.

As you "forget" the reference to the shared pointer when you leave the function it will automatically reclaim the memory assigned at that point - leaving you with a pointer to an invalid memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Your `shared_ptr` in your function is the only one referencing the pointer to your `vector`. When it goes out of scope (when the function returns), it therefore deletes the referenced pointer.

Make your function return a `shared_ptr` instead of a regular pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you read up on how shared_ptr should be used, cause you're doing it all wrong.. It's meant to not having to deal with raw pointers anymore, definitely not mixing them. Basically you pass around the shared_ptr instance like you used to with raw pointers, but without having to care about deleting it anymore. Do this instead:

```
typedef std::vector< int > my_vector;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< my_vector > my_vector_ptr;

my_vector_ptr func()
{
  my_vector_ptr vec( boost::make_shared< my_vector >() );
  vec->push_back(123);
  return vec.get();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  my_vector_ptr result = func();
  cout << result->at(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use back inserter to avoid mixing inserting and returning the same vector. Let the client specify witch type of vector it is ... thus making the function template-able.

code:

```
typedef std::vector< int > my_vector;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< my_vector > my_vector_ptr;

template <typename OutputIterator>
void func1(OutputIterator it)
{
   // std::copy (anotherVector.begin(), anotherVector.end(), it);
   *it++ = 123; 
}

void func2(my_vector& v)
{
   v.push_back(123);
}

int main()
{
    my_vector_ptr vec( new my_vector() );
    func1(std::back_inserter(*vec)); // func is now an algorithm .. 
    func2(*vec);
}
```

In `func1`, the signature of the function says what this function does. You can't erase from vector, you can't do anything else, just what it says. Insert.

Think of `func1` as an algorithm.